# Act/Act day count convention discrepancy between Quantlib and Bloomberg Calculator - any solutions?

Tags: bloomberg, quantlib

Quantlib does not match BC4 Bloomberg Calculator for Act/Act day count convention. It doesnt match the pricipal which is the price to 6dp.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWZyZ.png)

Does anyone have a suggestion for this please?

Thank you

It appears that this is due to SimpleDayCounter defaulting to 30/360. However, using ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA) or ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISDA) does not work because of how it cannot account for the actual coupon in each coupon period.

Comment: The sample code and BBG screenshot are in the attached image

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA, schedule)` to account for the coupon periods.